# How do I update an installed feature?

Tags: 8, features

Using the module Features in Drupal 8, if I export them and install them in a different site. When there are changes and exported again, if I replace the files in the destination site, how can I update the installed features? I can't find anywhere in the UI to do it.

I can't use drush.